# A Riddle for a Friend of Mine

Tags: riddle

> My eye is not quite precious.
>   My ear is not quite a dandy lion.
>   My tongue is not quite barbed.
>   My whiskers are flowery.
>   My vocalization is something remarkable.
>   My hand is used by another.
>   My tail might be eaten, built on, or lived in.
>   My sleeping place is a manipulative game.
>   My sleepwear is quite outstanding.
>   My scratch can infect you.
>   My ash is what some call home.
>
> **What am I?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you

> **A Cat**

My eye is not quite precious.

> [Cat's Eye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrysoberyl#Cymophane) is a semiprecious gemstone.

My ear is not quite a dandy lion.

> [Hypochaeris Radicata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypochaeris_radicata) which is also called cat's ear or dandelion.

My tongue is not quite barbed

> May be referring to [Cat tongue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_tongue) chocolate *bar*. And cats do have quite barbed tongue.

My whiskers are flowery.

> [This flowery plant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthosiphon_stamineus) is also called Cats Whiskers.

My vocalization is something remarkable.

> ["The cat's meow,"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat's_meow) an expression referring to something that is considered outstanding; coined by American cartoonist Thomas A. Dorgan (1877–1929)

My hand is used by another.

> [Cats paw](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat%27s_paw) is that phrase. Thanks @M Oehm

My tail might be eaten, built on, or lived in.

> [Cattail](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typha) also called Typha has all these capabilities.

My sleeping place is a manipulative game.

> [Cats Cradle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat%27s_cradle) is that game. Thanks @M Oehm

My sleepwear is quite outstanding.

> May be [Cats Pajamas](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cat%27s_Pajamas)

My scratch can infect you.

> Yes. [Cat Scratch Disease](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat-scratch_disease)

My ash is what some call home.

> [Cats Ash](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat's_Ash) is a hamlet.

Title

> Might be referring to [He was a friend of mine by Cat Power](http://www.metrolyrics.com/he-was-a-friend-of-mine-lyrics-cat-power.html)

Comment: But as far as I know... there's also a gem-stone called Cat's-Eye and that's quite precious...isn't it ? @Techidiot ?

Comment: Yes. Indeed it is a little costly. That is the reason why I preferred toy over it. :)

Comment: I always think of cat's eyes as the reflector things in bicycle spokes and on roadside posts. There's a game called [cat's cradle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat%27s_cradle) where you manipulate strings. For the hand, see [cat's paw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat%27s_paw).

Comment: And for the tail that you can eat, build on and live in: [cattail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typha).

Comment: @M Oehm - Yes. I came across Typha. Didnt read the edible part of that. Thanks. Updating shortly.

Comment: Okay, sorry, didn't want to cut you short. The overall solution is a good find, by the way.

Comment: Cat's Eye is a semiprecious gemstone (and thus "not quite precious"). Also you're not quite correct with vocalization; see if you can find that one :)

Comment: @Rubio It's showing quite high price in India :p And I have added something else for vocals now. Let me know if it meets your demands ;)

Comment: @Rubio I think I got it now.

Comment: Still no. It's a lot like the sleepwear entry. Like, a *lot* like it.

Comment: @Rubio Cat phone?Cat S60?

Comment: When you find it, my previous comment will absolutely confirm it.

Comment: There it is :) +1